# Python aiohttp - login into page and getting content

Tags: python, aiohttp

I've been trying for days to use aiohttp to login to a website and then navigate to the admin area to get the content. After I post the Session I'm not sure what to do in order to get the content from the admin page. I have also attempted this by grabbing the cookies from the session but I'm unsure what to do after grabbing the cookies. This code section has been commented out as it is not the preferred way.

```
async def do_task(session, credentials):
    try:
     async with session.get(credentials['domain']) as r:
         url = r.url #follow redirect to login page
         login_data = {"log": credentials['username'], "pwd": credentials['password']}

         # Please help with below
         await session.post(url, json=login_data)
         return await r.get(f'{url}admin').text()

        # #Attempt with cookies
        #  async with session.post(url, json=login_data) as login:
        #      session.cookie_jar.update_cookies(login.cookies)
        #      return await login.get(f'{url}admin').text()

    except Exception as e:
     print(e)

async def tasks(session, dict_list):
    tasks = []
    for credentials in dict_list:
        task = asyncio.create_task(do_task(session, credentials))
        tasks.append(task)
    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return results

async def main(x):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        data = await tasks(session, x)
        return data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dict_list = ({
        "username": 'test',
        "domain": 'http://url.com/admin',
        "password": 'enter'
    },
    )

    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy()) #for windows
    results = asyncio.run(main(dict_list))
```

The error message I get is `'ClientResponse' object has no attribute 'get'`

I have previously done this exact same thing with requests using the below code but I'm trying to speed things up with aiohttp.

```
            with requests.Session() as login_request:
                login_data = {"log": x['username'], "pwd": x['password']
                              }
                login_request.post(url, data=login_data)
                source_code = login_request.get(url).content
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here:

> r.get(f'{url}/admin').text()

In your case `r` is `ClientResponse`(is not `ClientSession`. is `async with session.get(credentials['domain'])` result).

You can receive cookies asynchronously and then use them for asynchronous scraping. Should be something like this:

```
async def login(session, domain: str, login_data: dict):
    async with session.post(domain + '/admin', data=login_data) as resp:
        # I don't know how you check success login...
        # data = await resp.json() or data await resp.text()
        # if data... blablabla
        return [domain, resp.cookies]

async def process_page(session, url: str, cookie: SimpleCookie):
    async with session.get(url, cookie_jar=cookie) as resp:
        content = await resp.text()
        # do something + return...

# example logins = [{'domain': '...', 'login_data': {...}}, ...]
# get cookies for all users and domains
cookies = await asyncio.gather(*[
    login(session, l['domain'], t['login_data'])
    for l in logins
])
      
# processing '/page1' for all domains and users 
result = await asyncio.gather(*[
    process_page(session, c[0] + '/page1', c[1])
    for c in cookies
])
```